# Create a custom task in Gradle wrapping an existing one

Tags: java, gradle

I'm using **Gradle** to manage the SDLC of a Java project which takes some command-line parameters to change its default behaviour. For example, with the option `-t` the java app times its own execution time.

Doing it with Gradle is possible by running:

```
$ ./gradlew run --args="-t"
```

I wonder if there's a way in Gradle to define a custom task (let's say I wanna call it `time`) which basically would wrap over the `run` task and automatically append the `--args="-t"` option.

To be pragmatic, I would like to achieve with:

```
$ ./gradlew time
```

the same behaviour achieved with `run --args="-t"`.

Thank you.

Comment: Show the `run` task.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this indeed. Since the `run` task is of type `JavaExec` you could just create your own task that extends from `JavaExec`:

```
task time(type: JavaExec) {
  group = 'run'
  description = 'Run the application with measuring the execution time'

  classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  mainClass = 'com.yourcompany.MainClass'
  args '-t'
}
```

You can read more about application plugin (and the `run` task) [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_usage)

Comment: `group = 'run'` doesn't wrap the `run` task. OP hasn't shown the `run` task, but that may be a `JavaExec` too, making this redundant.

Comment: Of course it doesn't wrap the `run` task, the group is there actually just for the sake of displaying it nicely. You can name it whatever you want, but logically it has to be in the `run` or `execution` group. the `run` task is for sure the `JavaExec` one, since the question is about the java project

Comment: If `run` is a `JavaExec`, what is the need for this task?

Comment: To add a default argument, which is exactly what OP asked for?

Comment: You’re missing my point. You created a task that has absolutely nothing to do with the existing `run` task. I asked why the `run` task can’t add a parameter, and you’ve not answered that question yet.

Comment: I'm not missing your point, because so far, you have not asked "Why the `run` task can't add a parameter". This is the first time I see it in this thread. Know any other way to wrap the `run` task? Then post your answer below and that's it.

Comment: And JFYI, this task fully replicates the `run` task from the application plugin, with a small addition of the default argument `-t`, so saying "has nothing to do with existing `run` task" is kinda wrong.